# Excel.Application not working in PowerShell using SQL Job, but works from command line

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using PowerShell to unlock a locked Excel spreadsheet.  When I run the script from a job (using myself as the Proxy user), the Excel portion of the script does not run.  When I execute the same script directly from the command line, however, it works fine.  My code is:

```
#Unlock Attatchment 
$x = New-Object -comObject Excel.Application
$x.visible = $false
$x.DisplayAlerts = $False
$workbook = $x.Workbooks.Open($spreadsheetFileName,1,$false,
                              5,$spreadsheetPassword,$spreadsheetPassword)
$workbook.SaveAs($tmpFileName,1,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,
                $x.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,
                $null,$null,$null,$null)
$x.Workbooks.Close()
$x.Quit()
```

Edit:  I added logging.  Here are the log results:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "6" argument(s): Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file "_____"
There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

Comment: I think that for some reasons (perhaps 64 bit SQL) the COM object is not loadable in the SQL job. Do you try to put your code into a try{}catch{} just to log the exception ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok!  Turns out the solution is as follows (in case this shows up in a search result):

1. Add Directory: `C:\Temp`
2. Add Directory: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Two years after answering, and you really saved my day.  Thank you!

Comment: To resolve this issue:
----------------
1. Added following folders and uncheck Read-Only for both (Desktop) folders: 

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop 
 & C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
-------------
2. Make sure SQL job proxy should be the Author for Excel file

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 2012 x64 I also had to create the folder below before it worked.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution included creating these two folders:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Comment: Also make sure SQL job proxy should be the Author for Excel file

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue:

1. Added following folders and uncheck Read-Only for both (Desktop) folders:
   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
2. Make sure SQL job proxy should be the Author for Excel file